# Iterate once over list, but return two lists

Tags: java

I have a `List<Foo>`: `foos`. And I have two methods that return `Bar`: `Bar doThingOne(Foo foo)` and `Bar doThingTwo(Foo foo)`. I want to end up with two `List<Bar>`s – one by iterating over `foos` and applying `doThingOne()` to each `Foo`, and the other by doing the same thing but with `doThingTwo()`. Is it possible to do this without iterating over `foos` twice?

Comment: can you add sample code which you have?

Comment: Its really something you can do after a couple of google searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it what you want? It's so simple that I have some doubt.

```
List<Bar> lb1 = new ArrayList<Bar>();
List<Bar> lb2 = new ArrayList<Bar>();
for (Foo f : foos) {
    lb1.add(doThingOne(f));
    lb2.add(doThingTwo(f));
}
```

Comment: old school...just what you want!

Comment: Haha, yup. Simple, but this is the answer. I was way overcomplicating things in my head.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with stream :

```
List<Bar> barList1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Bar> barList2 = fooList.stream().peek(f -> barList1.add(doThingOne(f))
    .map(f -> doThingTwo(f)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is a poster child case for why this rush to functional programming and streams is, IMO, overdone.  I've been programming for decades, and that jumble scares the heck out of me. This wouldn't survive one of my code reviews. - perfect time for the adage "just because you CAN do something...."